# How to open multiple documents using vb.net file explorer?

Tags: vb.net

I made a file explorer using vb.net the way I wanted it but the problem is that I have several test folders and every day I will put several pdf files and images inside those folders and when I enter the folder test1 I have the pdf file newtest and I have other files and when I go to click on a file it opens this file only if I put the path of the pdf file newtest preset and when I click on another it opens the other file if I put preset but I go have over a thousand image files and more than a thousand pdf files in these folders and I want to know what the code would be for when I click on a file it opens and when I click on another file the other file opens.
I can only do this with each pre-selected file and this is not feasible.

As the code shows:

Else

Process.Start ("C: \ Test \ test1 \ newtest.pdf")
        End If

I want it to open multiple files when I click each one of them one by one without having to be writing this code for each image and pdf file name separately.

Help me with this, please?

[Image with file explorer design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zzFn.jpg)

```
Public Class Form1
Dim path As String
Dim nextPath As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    On Error Resume Next
    path = TextBox1.Text
    If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(path)) Then

        explorer.Clear()

        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

        Next
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox("Its A File")
        'or user
        'pocess.Start(path) // to open the file
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    On Error Resume Next
    path = "C:\Test"
    For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
        explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

    Next
    For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
        explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles explorer.ItemSelectionChanged
    nextPath = path + "\" + e.Item.Text

End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles explorer.SelectedIndexChanged


End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles explorer.MouseDoubleClick
    On Error Resume Next
    If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(nextPath)) Then
        path = nextPath
        explorer.Clear()
        TextBox1.Text = path
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

        Next
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
        Next
    Else

        Process.Start("C:\Test\test1\newtest.pdf")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click

End Sub

Private Sub BtnForward_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnForward.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: my comment will not solve this specific problem BUT (just saying) you can use webBrowser to do this, give it a try... 

just add your path in the URI property and you're good to go...

a lot of people don't know that the webbrowser control can also act like a good file explorer, and it just works great like you want it to.

Comment: Any code containing `On Error Resume Next` is bad code.

Comment: I agree with jmcilhinney, try using a `try catch` instead

Comment: I understood but I do not know how to do this.  I'm a beginner in VB.NET and this code I found with searches on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you still want to go with clicking on listview items to open it try this:

`process.start(path & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text)`

this will open C:\test\test1\newtest.pdf (for example)

Update:

look, it worked for me, double clicking "internet tester.exe" opens it.
if your "path" does not contain "\" at the end make sure to add it yourself.
mark the answer as answer if it works for you too

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've put this command but it already gives a start error that says "ListView1 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its level of protection" and I follow the possible corrections that Visual Studio gives me that is "generate ListView1 variable" and so  the error no longer appears, but when I run the program and click on a file there it says "System.NullReferenceExcption: object variable or variable with block not defined.

Comment: Error says you don't have anything called listview1, do you? Or did u remove it or renamed it to something else?

Comment: Do not rename anything in the code, it's still the same as I said in the main question.

Comment: if you call your listview1 "explorer" than use explorer, check my updated answer

Comment: Yes, I used Explorer instead of ListView1 and it worked, now anyone I click is opening as it should.  Example if I enter in the folder test5 and click on test.pdf it opens the file and if I go in another path and click on some PDF file it opens the right file.  So now it's working.  I thank you very much for this, you helped me very much, thank you very much from the heart.

Comment: no problem, please mark my answer above as answer :)

Comment: Now to finish just one more question, the back and forth buttons which command should I give to when I enter C: \ test \ test1 I click the back button it goes to C: \ test and when I click the button to  front it goes to C: \ test \ test1 again and so with whatever folder it is to enter and exit.  Can you help me with this too?

Comment: sure, but it will work only if you want to go back, because if you want to go forward it won't know which folder to take you to, to go back you can do: `path = path.substring(0, path.lastindexof("\"))`

Comment: make sure to record something with the arrow key like a modifier like this:
    `If e.KeyCode  =  Keys.left AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.shift Then
    path = path.substring(0, path.lastindexof("\"))
    End If`

Comment: I understand, I put the code and an error in "lastindexof is not declared ..." and I make the possible correction that Visual Studio gives me and there goes without the error and when I will run the program and press the button back it closes  the program and displays the error "System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: i edited that after a second :) try it
it's path.lastindexof

Comment: be careful the software tries to give you options to correct your code, but it doesn't mean if it gives you 1 option meaning it's the correct one..

Comment: It gave error in "KeyCode is not a member of EventArgs" and Modifiers gave the same error, and in "End If should be preceded by corresponding if"

Comment: i thought you knew sorry, you should do this in a keydown event, and i already added `if` in my comment make sure you have it too, copy it as is

Comment: Sorry for the delay to reply.
I do not understand now what it is to do, it just has the errors in KeyCode and Modifiers as I said.

Comment: you should use the textbox1 keydown event, it won't work in another event than keydown, make sure textbox1 has focus when you click shift + left, and make sure you have textbox1's "key preview" property set to TRUE. if it didn't work you can do it on listview's event or form's event, just make sure "key preview" is TRUE.
you will find all these answers on google now, we are just spamming this topic. I'm just glad i could help you get going with your little project.

Comment: I do not know how to do what you said, I do not understand yet.  But that's okay, you've really helped me.  Thank you very much.